# Set custom browser for http protocol

Tags: windows-10, browser, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I'm devlopping a small browser, ans i'm intersting to set it as default browser of windows
i know how to set that when a html file is cliked, it will open my browser, bit i can't find out how to set that when windows want to open an url, it will be in my browser.
for example, when i open a word document and there is an url into it, if i click on the url it open the internet browser.
i want it to be my browser, but how can i do this?

thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of windows is this for - this is normally set via the default applications, but it depends on the version of windows.

Comment: 10.it's not possible via the defaults applications, it give me only a few browsers (chrome, edge, iexplorer), and i can't add my browser there